# Parallel negative verbs in Present Perfect

Tags: parallelism

Which one is correct?

- "I have not done(any verb1) or done(any verb2) something"
- "I have not done(any verb1) or have not done(any verb2) something"
- "I have not done(any verb1) or not done(any verb2) something"

where something part is related semantically only to second verb.
I.e: "I have not showered or have not eaten breakfast"

Comment: You can use **neither...nor** to make parallel negatives in a sentence: *I have neither showered nor eaten breakfast*.

Comment: @mahmudkoya yes, you are right, I could use it. Just was interested with specifically this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I have not showered or have not eaten breakfast."

This is not correct. Instead, you should say:

> 1. I have **not** ***showered*** or ***eaten*** / ***had*** breakfast (yet).
> 2. I have **neither** showered **nor** eaten / had breakfast (yet).
> 3. I have **not** ***showered***, **nor** have I ***eaten*** / ***had*** breakfast (yet).

Please observe the inversion between subject and predicate in **3**.

Comment: Does it means that it is not important to what part of parallel verbs the subject is related (in this example - "breakfast"). For example consider the difference - "I have not liked or commented any post" where the subject (post) is related to both verbs.